# Installing/Using koma-script with TeX Live on Kali-Linux

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, linux, scrlttr2, debian

Please help me. I really need to build a pdf asap on Kali Linux. The CV.tex is 100% error-free. I want use pdflatex:

```
pdflatex CV
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) 

(preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./CV.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `scrlttr2.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

pdflatex tells me scrlttr2.cls lacks. scrlttr2 is koma-script right? How do I install koma-script on my TeX Live distribution?

latex --version brings:

```
latex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.24; using libpng 1.6.24
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.44.0
```

uname -a brings:

```
uname -a
Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I install the koma-script package from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=de properly so I can build the pdf with pdflatex?

Kind regards
Robert

Answer (score 1):

KaLi is a debian based linux distribution. [For debian linux KOMA-Script is part of `texlive-latex-recommended`](https://packages.debian.org/cgi-bin/search_contents.pl?word=koma-script&searchmode=searchfilesanddirs&case=insensitive). So

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

should install it.

If you need the most current KOMA-Script release you can use the TDS-archive from [the KOMA repository](https://komascript.de/current). But using this is for experienced users only.